# An exercise of inheritance in Java

Tags: java, inheritance

I've already written a program of inheritance in Java ; Box and Line are subclasses of Shape and draw() is function of Shape.in InherPaint class I wrote menu() and display() functions also. when I want to Add Line or Add Box Separately the result is fine , but whenever I Add Line and after that Add Box ,the result is wrong . I think the problem is for my wrong definition of Shape array and the way I used it with indexShapeBox and indexShapeLine . my code is here :

```
    package inherpaint;

    import java.util.Scanner;

public class InherPaint {

Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
Shape[] listShape = new Shape[80];
int indexShapeBox = 0;
int indexShapeLine = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    InherPaint p = new InherPaint();
    p.menu();
}

void display() {

    System.out.println(" *** Paint System ***");
    System.out.println("1.Add box");
    System.out.println("2.Add line");
    System.out.println("3.Show all");
    System.out.println("4.Erase all");
    System.out.println("5.Exit");

}

void menu() {

    int option = 0;
    while (option != 5) {

        display();
        option = key.nextInt();
        switch (option) {

            case 1:
                System.out.println(" Please enter a nomber for sizeX : ");
                int X = key.nextInt();
                System.out.println(" Please enter a nomber for sizeY : ");
                int Y = key.nextInt();
                Box b = new Box(X, Y);
                listShape[indexShapeBox] = b; // problem must be here !
                indexShapeBox++;

                break;

            case 2:
                System.out.println(" Please enter a nomber for sizeZ : ");
                int Z = key.nextInt();
                Line l = new Line(Z);
                listShape[indexShapeLine] = l; // problem must be here !
                indexShapeLine++;

                break;

            case 3:
                for (int i = 0; i < indexShapeBox; i++) {
                    listShape[i].draw();
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < indexShapeLine; i++) {
                    listShape[i].draw();
                }

                break;

            case 4:
                indexShapeBox = 0;
                indexShapeLine = 0;

                break;

            case 5:
                System.out.println("Exit!");

                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Error");

            }

        }

    }

 }
```

and this is Shape class:

```
    package inherpaint;

    public abstract class Shape {

         int sizeX,sizeY,sizeZ;
         public abstract void draw();

 }
```

and this is Box class :

```
    package inherpaint;

    public class Box extends Shape {

      public Box(int sizeX, int sizeY) {
         this.sizeX = sizeX;
         this.sizeY = sizeY;
}

    @Override
    public void draw() {

        for (int i = 0; i < sizeX; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < sizeY; j++) {
                System.out.print("-");

            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

and this is Line class:

```
    package inherpaint;

    public class Line extends Shape {

      public Line(int sizeZ) {
      this.sizeZ = sizeZ;
}


    @Override
    public void draw() {

        for (int j = 0; j < sizeZ; j++) {
            System.out.print("-");

        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a separate counter for lines and boxes, even though you store them in the same array. That's your problem. You only need a single counter.

Consider this code :

```
        case 1:
            ...
            listShape[indexShapeBox] = b;
            indexShapeBox++;
            ...
        case 2:
            ...
            listShape[indexShapeLine] = l;
            indexShapeLine++;
```

If you add a box and then add a line, they would be added to the same index of the `listShape` array, so the line reference would overwrite the box reference.

Change your code to :

```
        case 1:
            ...
            listShape[indexShape] = b;
            indexShape++;
            ...
        case 2:
            ...
            listShape[indexShape] = l;
            indexShape++;
```

Your drawing loop should also be simplified :

```
        case 3:
            for (int i = 0; i < indexShape; i++) {
                listShape[i].draw();
            }
```

Comment: thanks but with these changes it doesn't show the correct answer even when I call Add Box and Add Line separately ! . @eran

Comment: @M.ds Did you switch to a single index variable? What output do you get if you add one box and one line?

Comment: yes , I've done as you said . I entered  2 for sizeZ to add one line and output was : ---- @eran

Comment: @M.ds you have to add System.out.println(); in draw() method

Comment: @CrazyJavaLearner thanks , the previous answer is correct . I mistakenly forgot to delete one of FOR in Case 3